¿Por qué no puedo utilizar un cuarto Servlet en JAVA EE?
Tengo la siguiente situación: Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en el que inicialmente utilicé 3 servlets y todo funcionó muy bien, el problema fue cuando intenté crear un cuarto servert. Por alguna razón que no he podido entender, ningún JSP quiso conectarse con ese último servlet (aparece el clásico Estado HTTP 404 - No encontrado: El recurso requerido [...] no está disponible), se conecta con cualquiera de los otros tres, y con sus respectivos GET y POST, demostrando asi que el problema no esta en el Apache Tomcat, pero simplemente no lo hace con este cuarto. Cabe destacar que lo he verificado y efectivamente no tengo errores de escritura. No sé si hay alguna limitación en las opciones de cantidad de servlets que se permiten usar, de modo que mi proyecto está limitado a un máximo de tres servlets, o si es otro tipo de problema. Como entorno de desarrollo estoy usando NetBeans.
Intenté eliminar el cuarto servlet y recrearlo, y también intenté invocarlo en un JSP diferente, sin embargo, sucede lo mismo.
A continuación se muestra el JSP desde el que se llama.
<h1>Iniciar sesion</h1><br>
<% String mensaje = request.getParameter("mensajeError");
    if(mensaje == null){
        mensaje="";
    }

%>

<form action="SvLoggin" method="POST">
<div class="form">
<label>Usuario</label><br>
<input type="text" id="user" name="usuario"><br>
<label>Contraseña</label><br>
<input type="password" id="pass" name="contraseña"><br>
<div id="verificacion"><p><%=mensaje%></p></div>
<button onclick="" class="button"> Inicio </button><br>
</div>
</form>

y este es el servlet
 @WebServlet(name = "SvLoggin", urlPatterns = {"/SvLoggin"})

public class SvLoggin extends HttpServlet {
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet SvLoggin</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet SvLoggin at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}

pero el resultado es:

gracias de antemano su valiosa colaboracion

añade tu web.xml tal vez el mapeo sea incorrecto
